# Can any data be transformed into a standard normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, standardization

There is a standardized transformation which can transform a normal distribution to standard normal distribution:
$$x^{(i)}=\frac{x^{(i)}-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}$$

I am wondering **given a uniform distribution or any other distribution, can we transform it into a standard normal distribution using the above equation?**

It is difficult to see from the following codes.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    x = np.random.randint(0, 10000, (1, 100))
    y = np.random.randint(0, 4000, (1, 100))
    
    z = np.random.randn(1, 100)
    
    x_s = (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
    y_s = (y - y.mean()) / y.std()
    
    # plt.hist(x_s, bins=1)
    # plt.show()
    
    import seaborn as sns
    
    # sns.distplot(x, rug=True, bins=None)
    sns.distplot(x_s, rug=True, bins=None)
    # sns.distplot(z, rug=True, bins=None)
    
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You've provided a counterexample yourself: $X \sim U(a,b)$. Your proposed transformation produces another uniformly distributed RV (left as an exercise: find the support of this new RV).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83166/discussion-on-question-by-tyler--can-any-data-be-transformed-into-a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding or subtracting a value from a random variable (or set of samples) will shift the distribution. Multiplying or dividing by a value will scale it. Standardizing (i.e. subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation) will force the mean to zero and the standard deviation to one. But, this is just a particular way of shifting and scaling; it can't change the fundamental shape of the distribution. So, if the distribution isn't normal to begin with, standardizing won't make it normal.

For example, here's an example of a non-normal distribution before and after standardizing. You can see that it has been shifted and scaled, but the shape is the same:[image]

Comment: This is a very limited concept of transformation.  In general, any random variable can be transformed into a normal random variable (see my answer below).

Comment: As a previous comment suggested, this is a very limited definition of transformation.  It misses the technique of inverse normal scores transformation, which basically just maps the data to a normal distribution.

Comment: @SalMangiafico: limited or not, the question asks about exactly this kind of affine transformation, "**can we transform it into a standard normal distribution using the above equation?**"

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you want to find the density $f_{z}(z_i)$ of the random variable
$$
z_i = \frac{x_i-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}
$$
where $\mu_x = \operatorname E(x_i)$ and $\sigma_x^2 = \operatorname{Var}(x_i)$.

Using the rule of variable transformation we have that
$$
f_{z}(z_i) = f_{x}(x_i(z_i)) \left|\frac{\partial x_i(z_i)}{\partial z_i}\right|
$$
where $f_{x}(\cdot)$ is the density of $x_i$,  and $x_i(z_i)$ is $x_i$ written as a function of $z_i$, i.e.
$$
x_i = z_i\sigma_x+\mu_x.
$$
We have also that
$$
\left|\frac{\partial x_i(z_i)}{\partial z_i}\right| = \sigma_x.
$$
It is easy to see that this produces a standard normal only if $f_x(\cdot)$ is normal.